# Media queries for Ipad mini with retina display?

Tags: ipad, media, retina

for Ipad mini(non-retina):

```
@media screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)
```

for Ipad 3&4(retina):

```
@media screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

but how about Ipad mini with retina display?

Comment: It the same as the iPad 3&4. Since the iPad has the resolution as a normal iPad. Just a smaller screen.

Comment: My client is requesting a different style on ipad normal and ipad mini. Since the actual device for ipad mini is smaller. If I use back the media query for ipad 3&4 on mini(retina) then it will serve the ipad normal style within the mini(retina), which is not consistent when switching between the retina and non-retina version in mini.

Comment: To you site an iPad mini is the same as a normal iPad.

Comment: Also the first media-query is also used for the iPad 1 and 2, which do not have retina displays. So you are already break the experience on those devices.

Comment: oh ya, I didn't notice that until you mention it

Comment: @rckoenes You should post an answer, since your comment solved the problem.